# SSD RAID 0 Setup for database application. What results should I look for?

Tags: raid, ssd

I guess for database applications Random 4K Read/Write values of the SSD should be the one which should be checked first.

The question is **how many queue depth should I check?** As far as I see Random 4K IOPS (1 Queue) would not change in RAID set ups, but it changes for multiple queues.

Thanks

Comment: Uuh, don't do it. RAID0 for anything in production, especially something as new (and thus potentially un-reliable) as SSD is just begging for total data loss.

Comment: The server won't be in production. :)

Comment: Well, I guess that's not so bad then...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS and database. If we're talking a recent SQL Server 2005 or later on Windows 2003 or later, I think it will issue up to 32 asynchronous IOs by default, so look at queue depth=32. This "max async IO" setting is auto-tuned by SQL Server and the OS.

For other databases and OS, you will likely have to experiment or tweak whatever settings are available. MySQL on one linux distribution might behave very differently than the same MySQL version compiled and packaged for a different distribution.